# JSON.parse length limit PhoneGap

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, cordova, windows-phone-7-emulator

I have a simple PhoneGap project that I am using the PhoneGap template in VS2010 and the emulator.

If I try to JSON.parse an array of objects from window.localStorage it will only work if the number of objects is less that about 200, in my case.

Is there a limit to the length of the JSON that I can parse?